# Split Seat arrangment with angular JS

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a cinema ticket booking system with Angular JS. I want to draw the seat structure with 3 zones.

I have zones 1)Platinum,2)Diamond,3)Gold

Now I can generate the seat layout with my below codes without zones. means like a table.

I want to split the seat layout with zones.

My Code.

```
 <div class="content" ng-controller="bookings">

            <p>Screen this way! :)</p>

            <table class="seatLayout">
                <tr>
                    <td class="padding-bottom"></td>
                    <td class="padding-bottom" ng-repeat="col in cols track by $index" ng-bind="col"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                    <td class="padding-right" ng-bind="row"></td>
                    <td class="seat" ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-click="seatClicked(row + col)" ng-switch on="getStatus(row + col)">
                        <img ng-switch-when="selected" src="{{URL::asset('images/seat_selected.png')}}">
                        <img ng-switch-when="reserved" src="{{URL::asset('images/seat_reserved.png')}}">
                        <img ng-switch-default src="{{URL::asset('images/seat_available.png')}}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
  </div>
```

Angular.

```
var todomvc = angular.module('iraqi-app', ['firebase']);
todomvc.controller('bookings', function TodoCtrl($scope, $firebase,$http) {
 $scope.rows = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
    $scope.cols = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];


    // Set reserved and selected
    var reserved = ['A2', 'A3', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'J1', 'J2', 'J3', 'J4'];
    var selected = [];


    // seat onClick
    $scope.seatClicked = function(seatPos) {
        console.log("Selected Seat: " + seatPos);
        var index = selected.indexOf(seatPos);
        if(index != -1) {
            // seat already selected, remove
            selected.splice(index, 1)
        } else {
            // new seat, push
            selected.push(seatPos);
        }
    }

    // get seat status
    $scope.getStatus = function(seatPos) {
        if(reserved.indexOf(seatPos) > -1) {
            return 'reserved';
        } else if(selected.indexOf(seatPos) > -1) {
            return 'selected';
        }
    }

    // clear selected
    $scope.clearSelected = function() {
        selected = [];
    }

    // show selected
    $scope.showSelected = function() {
        if(selected.length > 0) {
            alert("Selected Seats: \n" + selected);
        } else {
            alert("No seats selected!");
        }
    }
 });
```

Output..

[image]

I want the seat layout like this below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create JSON object to do it with specific requirement.
For example

```
$scope.rows = [
   {rowid :  'A', type:'Gold'},
   {rowid :  'B', type:'Gold'},
   {rowid :  'C', type:'platinum'},
   {rowid :  'D', type:'platinum'},
   {rowid :  'E', type:'platinum'},
   {rowid :  'F', type:'platinum'},
   {rowid :  'G', type:'platinum'},
   {rowid :  'H', type:'platinum'},
   {rowid :  'I', type:'Diamond'},
   {rowid :  'J', type:'Diamond'}];
```

And HTML something like this

```
  <div class="content" ng-controller="bookings">
        <table class="seatLayout">
            <!--- Arrange your layout accordingly -->
            <!-- Devide ur <tr> according to type of row -->
        </table>

        <p> Screen this way! :) </p>
   </div>
```

So that you can differentiate Premium or Gold or something